# Normal Map inverting while rotating while scene stays the same

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv, shaders, normals

So I am trying to create a loop around a spiraling street.
For this I'm moving the camera for a while and recreating the beginning at the end exactly. Loop-wise it works.

Here you can see the camera movement:

[image: Scene on Imgur]

After adding in a sunlight which rotates and moves with the camera (so it gives the impression of staying in the same place), I saw that the Normal Map of the street was behaving weirdly. It seems like it is inverting and then reverting again. I'm not doing a full circle around the spiral so it's not reverting fully.

You can see so in the render:

[image: Render on Imgur]

Now, I already figured it has something to do with the normal map. I'm guessing it also has something to do with the way the UV is projected. But I have no idea if that is the case and how I would go and fix it.

Here is the UV and the Normal Texture:

[image: Normal Map + UV]

I am using this UV in the shader of the material.

Thank you for taking the time to read.

Comment: Did you check your face orientation?

Comment: @Phönix64 yes, I dd, all fine.

Comment: Could you share the file using blend-exchange? I suspect it has to do with the ligthing